# How to make typescript transpile ES6 classes

Tags: typescript, es6-class

How can I make typescript to transpile ES6 classes into kind of emulations of classes. ES5/ES3 it must be if I understand it right.

My current tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

The eventual goal is to let my app to work in IE which complains about ES6 classes. Or should I resort to polyfills?

Comment: have you tried using `target:es3` ?

Comment: Yup, still classes are in bundle

Comment: I bundle down it with [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup), maybe you can try it.

Comment: Thanks, but want to stay with webpack since everything is configured

Comment: Then you have to look at a Babel plugin for webpack I think